# how to force the code to parse specific POST call response

Tags: python, python-requests, pytest

I'm making three post calls one by one and getting tree response. My code is always taking last response and passing it on. The question is how to force the code to parse second or first response not last one.
This is my method with for loop and range3.

```
    def create_card_on_the_board_call(self, id_list, card_count, card_name):
    global create_card
    for i in range(card_count):
        create_card = self.rest_api_helper.post_call(
            self.base_url + '/cards?' + 'key=' + test_config[
                'key'] + '&' + 'token=' + test_config[
                'token'] + '&' + f'idList={id_list}' + '&' + f'name={card_name}', headers=None)
    return create_card.json()
```

response looks like that received response {"id":"5f9dcffaa96f144d311deaa5","checkItemStates":[]}
I need id from first or second response not third. Also I need all three calls.
and this is how I'm calling the post

```
card_count = 3
card_name = 'someCard'
create_card_on_the_board = api_board.create_card_on_the_board_call(id_list=create_list_on_the_board["id"],
                                                                   card_count=card_count, card_name=card_name)
```

now my method is looking like this:

```
    def create_card_on_the_board_call(self, id_list, card_count, card_name):
    global create_card
    responses = []
    for i in range(card_count):
        create_card = self.rest_api_helper.post_call(
            self.base_url + '/cards?' + 'key=' + test_config[
                'key'] + '&' + 'token=' + test_config[
                'token'] + '&' + f'idList={id_list}' + '&' + f'name={card_name}', headers=None)
        responses.append(create_card)
    return responses[2].json()
```

and I could select which card I want to pass but still dont know how to use as a proper argument in next call? e.g.

```
new_card_name = 'NewCardName2'
update_card = api_board.update_card_call(card_id=create_card_on_the_board['id'], new_card_name=new_card_name)

def update_card_call(self, card_id, new_card_name):
    update_card = self.rest_api_helper.put_call(
        self.base_url + '/cards/' + f'{card_id}' + '?' + 'key=' + test_config[
            'key'] + '&' + 'token=' + test_config[
            'token'] + '&' + f'name={new_card_name}', headers=None)
    return update_card.json()
```

so here I want to use different create_card_on_the_board but I dont know how? Still taking the same card as in return responses[2].json(). I tried card_id=create_card_on_the_board[1]['id']
but its not working as this is not a list

Comment: You need to clearly define what you want to get out of calling your function given certain inputs.  What would make you decide to return the first or second response rather than the third?  Will there always be three requests?  If so, maybe you don't want to use a loop, because then you could do different things after each request.  It's really up to you.  The main thing is, know clearly what you want your code to do (write it down on paper!) before you try to code it up.

Comment: I understood that I want the three responses. Why don't you create a list before the for and append the results into it, then return the list.

Comment: @wviana - wow.  did we have the same idea, or what!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could put all of the responses in a list so you could get them all and then decide what to do with them. Here's how you'd do that:

```
def create_card_on_the_board_call(self, id_list, card_count, card_name):
    responses = []
    for i in range(card_count):
        create_card = self.rest_api_helper.post_call(
            self.base_url + '/cards?' + 'key=' + test_config[
            'key'] + '&' + 'token=' + test_config[
            'token'] + '&' + f'idList={id_list}' + '&' + f'name={card_name}', headers=None)
        responses.append(create_card)
    // Logic here determines which response to return and sets `x = 0, 1 or 2`
    return responses[x].json()
```

So now you have a list named `responses` after your loop completes, and you can do whatever you want with it.  I put a comment to show kinda what you seem to be talking about in your question.  You could just return the whole list with `return responses` and let the caller worry about which one to do what with.